# How to display a listitem count near Tab name?

Tags: android, tabs

I need to display the total list count near tab name in actionbar.I used this example to create tabs http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/
Kindly help me to display the count near Tab name.

Comment: Good that you found a sample to start from. But what is your problem/error? Please share code and problem!

Comment: @MattiasLindberg I need to display count of the listview near that tab name

Comment: Ok, problem was included. Sorry about that. But not many will download a sample, learn it and then try to answer your question. If you want an answer you should make an attempt yourself and share this code.

Comment: @Prasanna on which action you want to show the list count near tabname ?

Comment: @Sandy i need to list the count of the item near tabname on create method.

Comment: @Prasanna i have posted answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all i strogly recommand you to use the TabLayout this actionbar tabs are deprecated

but to solve you current issues do the following

Store your list item count to the array if its dynamic then you can use the array list

```
private int[] tabsCount = { 1, 10, 15 };
```

and change you for loop to this

```
for (int i=0;i<tabs.length;i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i] + " (" + tabsCount[i] + ")" )
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
```

Let me know in case of any issue

Comment: I dont need count of the tab.... I just want to display the list item count in the selected tab.

Comment: @Prasanna then you just need to set the tab text on the `onTabSelected` method like `tab.setText(tabs[tab.getPosition()] + " (" + countOfListItem + ")");`

Comment: I used like that, it displays null pointer exception. because i will get the count of the item after Async task executed.So it is showing null pointer exception.

Comment: @Prasanna so you need to update text onPost method of the asynctask if you still not get show me your code i will help